# Parent window highlight in taskbar / bring to front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow, taskbar

I have a web page where certain links open up a popup window, now if a user is about to be loggedout out we show a jquery layer stating that.

now if he user is still on the popup for a long time he never sees the log out layer and is then automatically logged out

Is there a way to 
1.Highlight the main window in the taskbar so the user can take notice and go there
2.Bring the window to the front

We do not want to show any mesage in the popup window

We also do not want to use html5 notifications for now

Also cannot use alert()  but need to replicate the behaviour of alert when my layer shows

Comment: Please post some code. What you've already done?

Comment: I believe the alert method in JQuery already has this functionality.... Try using that.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau canot use alert

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan it is a simple setTimeout() function to run a code after some time in the main window